# Marketing Cloudpages live landing page going blank

Tags: landing-page, cache

I have created a simple landing page that is now live. I had to make a simple test change and once I had saved the change the live page went blank for up to 20 minutes. Once it had come back up some browsers were still showing a blank page even an hour after the change. How can this happen, surely it isn't normal. The caching is extreme.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing...

Comment: Yes. Thank god I'm not the only one. The support seems to brush this off but I would think there are hundreds of others out there with the same issue.
This is a huge bug that is not acceptable for a live product.

Comment: Had a call yesterday with support about something related.  He did say that there's "sort of a bug".  He said that if I have a published page that I'm working on - updating stuff - that I should be publishing (instead of just saving to publish later).    I don't necessarily have an answer for WHY, but it does result in a blank page.

Comment: From SFMC: "Talked with customer, informed him if you makes changes to the cloudpage and don't republish, the cloudpage, will show blank."

Comment: Wow they should just rename the save button to "make your page blank" more and more I use CloudPages the more bugs and issues I seem to find.